# Why is Photoshop constantly asking about modifying color profiles when I open a file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I'm still rather new with understand the colour settings in any Adobe program. And I have noticed recently that my Photoshop KEEPS asking me again and again about the colour setting when I open a file.

I get this message everytime: 
[image]

This is my current colour settings:
[image]

I don't recall ever changing it recently or ever... So I really don't know what to do to get rid of the constant pop up. I mean... is there is a certain colour setting for people who design in Europe!? Haha help. So lost.

Comment: The "ask when opening" checkboxes will remove the popup. Whether or not that's a good thing for your for workflow, I don't know. I also don't know if you purposefully set the working RGB to use "Adobe RGB". sRGB may be better - again, depends upon your workflow.

Comment: @Scott Nothing is purposefully set... Nothing has ever been changed from the factory setting. Total newbie to understanding colour. *hides in shame* Haha, could you maybe help me learn/figure out what is the best setting? What would you need to know from me?

Comment: Well, there are no "best settings". The settings depend entirely upon your workflow and production, and even geographical region due regional production differences. Color management is a **huge**, mountainous, topic. It's not an easy answer. Sorry. Just offhand, switch the working RGB to sRGB if you're working on web/online images. Beyond that I'm not really comfortable giving any specifics with so little knowledge of the working/production environment. And.. I'm not in Europe so I don't even know what are preferred production setting there.

Comment: @Scott yeah tell me about it, I have been trying to no end to understand colour managment. I guess Google will be my friend. Thank you though, for whatever you could tell me. You mentioned sRGB for web/online. I work mostly with print. Does this mean you switch back and forth between print and web designs? Or is a colour setting something that must ALWAYS stick?

Comment: Eliza, if you are working mostly on print and the RGB images you get are from places like stock photo sites, you'll want the Working RGB to  be set to sRGB. That's the more common RGB profile (and it'l eliminate the warnings for the most part). The Adobe RGB is really just Adobe's setting they want to promote, it's not bad, but it's by no means "common" in RGB images.

Answer (score 1):

Color management gives a possiblity to have onscreen what colors the camera saw and also transfer the same possiblity forward when you give the image elsewhere. If you edited the colors on your computer before you give the image forward, the next watcher have a possiblity to see the same that was on your screen after the edits.

In addition you have a possiblity to see onscreen what CMYK printing would produce. That's essential in print production because CMYK print process cannot show all colors that you can see onscreen, there's more limited color range (=your screen can show much more brighter and saturated colors than CMYK prints, usual term for unprintable colors is "out of gamut").

With color management you have a possiblity to adjust your photo to fit into the used CMYK printing process and see acceptably a reliable preview (=proof) what will be printed.

I wrote "a possiblity" because you can switch the color management off. In addition you or others can have inferior screens which do not obey sRGB nor have any calibrated color profiles to correct with color management the colors they display. Finally one can use wrong color profiles. For example you will print on newspaper and watch the result onscreen as it would be printed onto best white glossy paper. In this case your client can have something nasty to say when he sees the result.

Many applications even do not have color management. At least CMYK printing will be a gamble without color management. If you work only for RGB screens, you can well succeed without color management if you stick with sRGB color range (its a bit narrower than Adobe RGB). That's because most computer screens today can show the sRGB range acceptably altough surely a little differently, but without smudging the colors too messy.

If the popping warning dialog bothers you, I recommend the following with RGB images:

1) Set working RGB space = sRGB

2) Set Color management policy for RGB = Convert to working RGB

3) Deselect all askings

This way you output images with sRGB range.

NOTE: This approach is useless if you work with CMYK or want to preserve the wider than sRGB color range of best cameras. In these cases your only option is to learn the color management theory and the needed practices.

Adobe's software is high priced because people are willing to pay for it. Many do so because the color management and its consistency between different Adobe's applications has proven its usefulness in everyday work.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer @user287001. I appreciate it. I work a lot with print, but my work is very mixed between print design and web design (I feel like that term is not correct today hmm). Could you recommend where to best start with CMYK colour management or how does one best work with both? :D